# React-Redux: Only One Prop Undefined in ComponentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this code in my container file:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   homes: Object.values(state.entities.homes),
   center: { lat: 37.7758, lng: -122.435 },
});
```

and this in my component file:

```
 <div>
   <div className="left-half" >
     <Map
       homes={homes}
       center={center}
     />
   </div>
   <div className="right-half">
     <HomeIndex 
       homes={homes} 
     />
   </div>
</div>
```

I am passing the same `homes` prop for both the `Map` and the `HomeIndex` containers but when I try to access it via `this.props.homes` in my `Map` container, it comes out as undefined.

What's strange is that `this.props.center` is defined while `homes` is not.

**It's important to note that in the `Map` container, I am accessing my props in a ComponentDidMount() method.**

I've searched around and I understand that ComponentDidMount will not grab the updated props but shouldn't the props be updated by the time it gets to my Map component since I'm grabbing it from my state in the container file?

Comment: Did you try using `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: I have tried using componentWillReceiveProps but then my props are not defined until I re-render my `Map`, which is not optimal. I would like that information to be there when I render my `Map` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it was coming up as empty was because the `ComponentDidMount()` in the child component ran before the `ComponentDidMount()` in the parent container. Therefore, when I was trying to pass `this.props.homes` from the parent to the child, it was undefined.

To solve this, I put `if(!this.props.homes) return null` at the top of my render function of my parent container so that I could wait for the ComponentDidMount() in my parent to run before rendering the children.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `home props` as **own property**.But in container,you are ***overwriting*** it with `state props`.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
   homes: Object.values(state.entities.homes), //state props get passed and not actual own props.
   center: { lat: 37.7758, lng: -122.435 },
});
```

In order to get passed own props,use `ownProps`.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
   homes: Object.values(ownProps.homes),//access home via ownProps
   center: { lat: 37.7758, lng: -122.435 },
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that `ownProps` shouldn't have been there in the first place. I want to get my information from the State, not ownProps.

Comment: the `mapStateToProps` is in your `Map` / `HomeIndex` container or is it in a parent container? If it is in the `Map` / `HomeIndex` container and you want the `homes` to be from the state you shouldn't have `homes={homes}`

Comment: @WangSheng as bjjeong said,he want to access using state.then it should in the `mapStateToProps`.And yes right he dont need to pass the home prop from parent container.

Comment: @WangSheng it is in the parent container

Answer (score 0):

If you want that map container's componentDidMount to have props value use it like this. By this, Map and HomeIndex will only render when `home` is not defined.

```
  <div>
     <div className="left-half" >
     {homes && 
       <Map
           homes={homes}
           center={center}
         />
     }
     </div>
     <div className="right-half">
      { homes && 
        <HomeIndex 
           homes={homes} 
        />
      }
     </div>
  </div>
```

To check the value of homes that reducer is returning, change your mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{ 
   console.log(state.entities.homes);
   return { 
      homes: Object.values(state.entities.homes),
      center: { lat: 37.7758, lng: -122.435 },
   }
};
```

Comment: This still returns an empty array for the `homes` prop in the `Map` container.

Comment: if it is returning empty array then the reducer is returning the empty array. Check the value of homes that reducer is returning by :

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  console.log(state.entities.homes);
  return  {
    homes: Object.values(state.entities.homes),
     center: { lat: 37.7758, lng: -122.435 },
  }};

Comment: @bjjeong anything on this?